# JavaScript - Smooth Movement / Resizing

Tags: javascript, html

How can I achieve smooth resizing or movement of an object over a period of time. Should I change the position of the object by units smaller than pixels? I am currently timing this using setTimeout, is there a more efficient way of moving an object over a period of time than setTimeout?

Comment: Smaller than pixels? next thing you'll be splitting atoms!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSS 3 Animation](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+3+animation) would probably be faster for browsers that support it, as it's based on native routines.

Other than that... `setTimeout` is how you do it. Though `setInterval` is probably going to make it easier to make your transitions.

You might take a look at some of the [javascript animation libraries](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+animation+library) and see what specific techniques they use. Or, you could look at stuff like [JavaScript Animation From Scratch](http://michaux.ca/articles/javascript-animations-from-scratch). Or the animation chapter in John Resig's Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja when he releases it. :)

Answer (score 3):

How about using jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function?  It's quite robust.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout() or setInterval().  You're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, setTimeout or setInterval is a good way to go.

There's also a variety of libraries, like jQuery, that have animation features built in, which can make life easier for you.