# Zoom image using CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming, css-transitions

So the best I could find to help have an image zoom a tad bit larger was this code:

```
onmouseover="this.width=175;this.height=75;" onmouseout="this.width=150;this.height=50"
```

Is there any better alternative to make it zoom larger, as in you can see it instead of the image just simply re-sizing in a blip?

Thanks :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the image to zoom smoothly. For that you need css3 transitions.

Comment: @MistressDavid Yes, smooth zoom :)

Comment: If you mean smooth resizing of an image, it already asked here JavaScript - Smooth Movement / Resizing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356312/javascript-smooth-movement-resizing

Comment: This question should not be closed, as it's not exact duplicate, here, OP is asking for a CSS solution as well

Answer (score 3):

How about doing this with pure CSS3 `transition` and `transform` by scaling the image..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bYFH/)

```
div {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

div:hover img {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}
```

You can refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13393595/1542290) for cross browser zoom properties.

---

Just set the `border` of the element correctly like [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bYFH/1/) (made `height` and `width` to `310px` because of `5px` `padding` on all sides)